# Declaring a class based on a concatenated string variable; changing scope of class variable

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am working on a project in which a Java program guesses correctly
The words in a wheel of fortune game, in which there can be any number of words.
These words to be guessed come from a dictionary of words that is generated from
a list of famous quotes.

I am representing each word as a class, and I holding the words to be guessed
in a arrayList of words. as...

And so I have something like...

```
public class WheelOfFortune
{


private Set<String> wofTempWordSource;
// this receives the world list
private List<word> SentenceElement = new ArrayList<word>();
// this array list contains and array list of the words in the sentence.


    public WheelOfFortune(Set<String> dictionary) 
    {
        // Implement me!
        wofTempWordSource = dictionary;
    } // end of WheelOfFortuneGuessSolver()
    
    
    
   public void newGame(int[] wordLengths) 
    { 
    
    int numSentenceElements = wordLengths.length;
        // this is the number of elements in the sentence.      
        
        String wrdName="";
        
        String wordName="";
        int wrdlngth=0;
        // This variable represents the word lens
        int wrdStrt=0;
        // This variable represents the index of the start of the word
        int wrdEnd=0;
        // This verbal represents the index of the end of the word
        int space =1;
        // this represents the one character to add for the space character 
        boolean wordGuessedCorrect = false;
        // This variable is a flag to indicate if the world has been 
        // successfully guessed of or not. 
        
        
        for (int wordnum = 1; wordnum <= numSentenceElements; wordnum++) 
        {
            wrdName = "w" + String.valueOf(wordnum);
            
            wordName= wrdName;
            
            wrdlngth = wordLengths[wordnum-1 ];
            
            
            
            word wordName =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
            SentenceElement.add(wordName  ) ;
            wordName.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);

            
            
        }// close  for (int wordnum = 1; wordnum <= numSentenceElements; wordnum++) 
        
        
         
    
    }
    
    public char makeAGuess() 
    {
        // Implement me!

        return '\0';
    } // end of makeAGuess()
    
    
     public void Feedback()
    {
        // Implement me!
    }
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

With this:

1. I get the error: `"Duplicate local variable wordName"`
2. the number of instances of the word class, can vary depend the number of words in the sentence, and so I am trying to use the following

   word wordName =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
   SentenceElement.add(wordName  ) ;

with "Wordname" as a String variable so that as this For loop loops through it does the following

```
    word W1 =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
    SentenceElement.add(W1  ) ;
   W1.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);
```

As so looping through and creating new instance of the word class as...

```
word W1 =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
SentenceElement.add(W1  ) ;
W1.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);


word W2 =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
SentenceElement.add(W1  ) ;
W2.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);

word W3  =  new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect );
SentenceElement.add(W1  ) ;
W3.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);

etc..
```

3. Because the word classes W1, W2,  W3   have been declared in newGame() they
   only have the scope in that method, but I need to make them globally available
   so they can be accessed by  makeAGuess(),  Feedback()... how?

Comment: #2 You've previously defined wordName as a String, and now you're redefining as a "word".

Comment: If word is a class, then Java naming conventions require that it start with a capital letter (Word).

Comment: Granted, but what I want to be able to do is dynamically declare "Word" objects and make them globally available...

Comment: You could use an ArrayList, but you cannot dynamically create variable names in Java. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to dynamically create new "Word" class instances as I will not know the length of the sentence and so I will not know the number of instance that I have to declare and make availalble....

Comment: You're allowed to create new Word instances all you want. You can add them to arrays, you can assign the reference to an existing Word reference.

Comment: Having variables with very similar names is confusing. wordName and wrdName, for example.

Comment: #3, create an ArrayList<Word> and use that to contain your new word objects.

Comment: Thank you..
I have declared the following globally...

private List<word> SentenceElement = new ArrayList<word>();
// this array list contains and array list of the words in the sentence.

Orignally I did the following..
SentenceElement.add(new word(wrdName, wrdlngth, wrdStrt, wrdEnd, wordGuessedCorrect )  ) ;

But i could not figure how I can access the new word element in the array list so I could
perform an operation such as 

..setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource);

Comment: As I have no named reference for the new word object instance... any suggestions 
how i return the named reference for the new word object instance, so I can 
acesss/operate using my class getters/setter?

Comment: Since you've never shown us the getters/setters, I have no idea.

Comment: Here is the example from my code before... W1.setTempWordSource(wofTempWordSource); this is setting into this word instance the word source... it is part of the "word" class..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223936/discussion-between-flash-jack-from-gundagai-and-nomadmaker).

Comment: You must put new question information into the question by editing it, please. And it sounds like you're making your Word class extremely complex. The goal of oop is to make the classes simple.